# pyVISA Timeout error connecting to a Tektronix MSO-4034B over ethernet

Tags: python

I'm having some issues trying to connect pyVISA to a Tektronix MSO-4034B over ethernet.  I can connect to it fine for example I can run:

```
>>>print(tek.query('*IDN?'))
TEKTRONIX,MSO4034B,C010722,CF:91.1CT FV:v1.38 DPO4USB:V1.00
```

Fine.  But running the following:

```
>>> values = np.array(tek.query_ascii_values('CURV?'))
```

Returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jkuechle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 455, in query_ascii_values
block = self.read()
  File "/Users/jkuechle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 332, in read
message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
  File "/Users/jkuechle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 306, in read_raw
chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "/Users/jkuechle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyvisa/ctwrapper/functions.py", line 1582, in read
ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))
  File "/Users/jkuechle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyvisa/ctwrapper/highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler
raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before 
operation completed.
```

Seems like I can pull any setting (WFMOutpre? also works) off the 4034B, but I can't get any data off of it.

My Code:

```
import visa
import numpy as np
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
tek = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::10.0.0.45::INSTR')
values = np.array(tek.query_ascii_values('CURVe'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can post a timeout in 25000ms using

```
tek.timeout = 25000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a delay for each write verb, example shows 1.2s delay or wait by using the following:

```
my_instrument = rm.open_resource("GPIB::10::INSTR", send_end=False, delay=1.2)
```